# Determining the middle of a line using latitude and longitude

Tags: r, geospatial

I have a large set of data with 7 stations along a river. During the collection of the data, samples were taken up and down a range of the river to get a representative idea of the environment. These aren't insignificant distances, the reaches can be over 50 miles over a curvy river. However, for the purposes of analysis, I've been asked to compress this data to a representative site in the middle of this reach using the latitude and longitude. This would be easy to do in GIS, but working with R I haven't been able to find a good method. I've tried taking the median of both the latitude and longitude and comparing them, but there's no overlap and I don't think that's a justifiable method. Is there a good package in R or a mathematical trick that I'm missing to find a median latitude, longitude pair?

Comment: `sf` package `st_centroid`, I'm not entirely sure but I think it can be applied to a Spatial Lines object.

Comment: without sample data, you probably won't get a better answer than @IanCampbell 's comment.

Comment: I agree with @hello_friend, [`sf::st_centroid`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sf/versions/0.9-3/topics/geos_unary) would work better, but I was having trouble finding the documentation for it.

Comment: @IanCampbell https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/sf.pdf page 21-23